# How do I turn every value in my dictionary to a float? (recursively)

Tags: python, dictionary

> d = { 'scores': 4,
>         'teams': { 'yellow': 11, 'blue': 4 }
>       }

How do I take a dictionary, and turn every integer into a float? Recursively, for every value max deep.

Comment: I really, really have to ask this... *Why?*

Comment: @Ignacio, because that's what it says on the homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def float_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if type(v) == dict:
            new_dict[k] = float_dict(v)
        else:
            new_dict[k] = float(v)
    return new_dict


>>> d = { 'scores': 4, 'teams': { 'yellow': 11, 'blue': 4 } }
>>> print float_dict(d)
{'scores': 4.0, 'teams': {'blue': 4.0, 'yellow': 11.0}}
```

Comment: +1 A one-liner with inline dictionary construction and ternary operator: `def float_dict(d):
    return dict((k, float_dict(v) if type(v) == dict else float(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())`

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_float(my_dict):
    for i in my_dict:
        if type(my_dict[i]) == dict:
            my_dict[i] = to_float(my_dict[i])
        elif type(my_dict[i]) == int:
            my_dict[i] = float(my_dict[i])
    return my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
defun rec-func (dictionary &optional (current 0))
  if dictionary[current] == dict:
    rec-func (dictionary[current], 0)
  else:
    dictionary[current] = float(dictionary[current])
    rec-func (dictionary current+1)
```

It's a recursive function but an iterative process and it's pseudo-code.
Also, don't forget to put into some conditional to check if you've reached the end.
Probably not the best solution, I haven't even tested it.

Hm, the problem really is getting a specific element of a dictionary but I think my function should work... I hope.

EDIT: Ooops, not properly indented, no idea how to do that though.

*edit (santa4nt)*: Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Santa, appreciate it :).

Comment: My solution will NOT work without using a OrderedDict, or so I believe. You could probably write a little longer version using the keys() method and stuff but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = { 'scores': 4, 'teams': { 'yellow': 11, 'blue': 4 } }
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d).replace("\nI","\nF"))
{'scores': 4.0, 'teams': {'blue': 4.0, 'yellow': 11.0}}
```

note `pickle` is recursive :)